# Populate CheckedListBox from Database and list

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to populate a checkedlistbox from a list

my approach:

```
SqlCommand getlocationnames = new SqlCommand("allLocationNames", conn);
getlocationnames.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure; 
conn.Open();
SqlDataReader dr = getlocationnames.ExecuteReader();
List<locations> results = new List<locations>();
while (dr.Read())
{
  locations newItem = new locations();
  newItem.loc_name = dr.GetString(0);
  results.Add(newItem);
}
dr.Close();

foreach (var result in results)
{
  checkedListBox1.Items.Add(result);
}
```

Does some one see what I'm missing here?

Comment: Use the debugger to step through the code line by line as it runs to see what is happening.  For testing, try using just `checkedListBox1.Items.Add(dr.GetString(0));`  Also make sure your `locations` class overrides the `ToString()` function.

Comment: ... or simply `checkedListBox1.Items.AddRange(result.ToArray()); checkedListBox1.DisplayMember = "loc_name";`

Comment: I answered your question by displaying a `GIF` result. If the response is helpful, please accept it and vote it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this approach (instead of two loops, one loop is used in this approach, which increases the application's speed):

Output:

[image: Output]

`SQL` (a `StoredProcedure` which is already created in the database):

```
Create Procedure AllValues As Select * From YourTableName
Go
```

`C#:`

```
    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection Connection = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection("Data Source =.;" + "AttachDbFilename = " + Application.StartupPath + @"\YourDataBaseName.mdf;" + "Integrated Security = True;");
    private void AddButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Connection.Open();
        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand Command = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand();
        Command.Connection = Connection;
        Command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        Command.CommandText = "AllValues";
        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader DataReader = Command.ExecuteReader();
        List<object> results = new List<object>();
        //DataReader[0] means the first column of the table
        //DataReader[1] means the second column of the table
        while (DataReader.Read())
        {
            results.Add(string.Join(null, "Country = ", DataReader[0].ToString(), "\t\t", "Capital = ", DataReader[1].ToString()));
        }
        Connection.Close();
        checkedListBox.Items.Clear();
        checkedListBox.Items.AddRange(results.ToArray());
    }
    private void ClearButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        checkedListBox.Items.Clear();
    }
```

Tested in:

`Visual Studio 2017`, `.NET Framework 4.5.2`, `Windows Forms`, `SQL Server 12.0.6024.0`

Comment: It is, "\t\t" are tabs right, i used list<locations> as i have a database connected and imported the data to entity model. should i still use it as a object?

Comment: If you mean "\t\t", no need to use it.